# duplicate checkmarks on scrolling tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, checkbox

I have a `tableView` which contains custom label and button(to set checkmark images).
I am able get all texts to the label correctly from array.But the button(checked/unchecked images) on selection shows checkmark but it disappears on scrolling and shows on another cell.
The cells are getting reused but I am unable to get individual selection and proper result.
The duplication happens on scrolling `tableView`. And also array does not append proper seletecd results.

**Below is the code.**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = tvSelectGroup.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellnewgroup")

    let device = userDeviceArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
     cell.slider.tag = indexPath.row
     if arraySensitivity.count==0
     {
     }else
     {
        cell.slider.value = Float(arraySensitivity[indexPath.row])
      }
    if let lbl = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
    {
        lbl.text = device
        lbl.textColor = UIColor.white
    }

    if let btnChk = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as? UIButton
    {
        print("button...")
        btnChk.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkboxClicked(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
        if btnChk.currentImage==#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Checkmark")
        {
            addDeviceInArray(cell: cell!)
        }
    }
    print("arr\(arr)")
    return cell!
}

@objc func checkboxClicked(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    print("checked..")
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}

@objc func addDeviceInArray(cell:UITableViewCell)
{
    let lbl = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
    if !arr.contains((lbl?.text)!)
    {
        arr.append((lbl?.text)!)
        print("array in label\(arr)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the array of states - false/true. Based on that change states of the cells or any content items.
2. Create you custom cell
3. Add handler inside cell on button pressing

For example:

```
var states: [Bool] = [true, true, false]
var deviceName[String] = ["PC", "Mac", "iPhone"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellnewgroup") as? MyCell

let device = deviceName[indexPath.row]
cell?.layer.cornerRadius = 10

if state[indexPath.row] {
   cell.button.setImage("uncheckmark")

} else {
  cell.button.setImage("checkmark")
}


cell.onClick = {

  state[indexPath.row] != state[indexPath.row]

}

if states[indexPath.row] {
    lbl.text = device
    lbl.textColor = UIColor.white
} else  { // remove this
    // print("button...")

// add button to cell class and use it.
   //print("arr\(arr)")
   //return cell!
}


class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton // connect to storyboard or create your own
    var onClick: () -> Void = {}



    // add this method to your cell, connect to storyboard or create your own target
    @IBAction func checkboxClicked(sender: UIButton) {

         onClick()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On click of checkboxClicked button, manage flag in userDeviceArray. Initially set 0 for all objects of array and on button click if that clicked row value was already checked set it to 0 else set it to 1 & reload the particular table cell. And in table cell add check with array object flag value.

I hope this helps.